# Enable Button From Main Controller after validating Textfield from another controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a function on my ViewController called **Validate()** and this function is being called after the textfield from another controller **DidEndEditing()**
However it gives me an error **Found nil while unwrapping optional value** when I'm going to enable the button..

ViewController:

```
  func validate() {

    var txtboxcount = 0
    var txtboxcountval = 0

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuestionsPage") as! QuestionsViewController


    var offer = NeedPaymentViewController.details.offer
    var address = NeedPaymentViewController.details.address



    var qsts = QuestionsViewController.question.qsts
    var total = QuestionsViewController.question.totalqsts

    print("qsts: \(qsts) and total: \(total) and offer: \(offer) and address : \(address)")



    if(offer != "" && address != "" && qsts == total) {
      saveBtn.isEnabled = true --> **Error happens Here "Found Nil" **
      saveBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
```

Another Controller:

```
   func validate() {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNeedPage") as! NeedDetailsController;
    vc.validate()
  }

   @IBAction func offerTxtDoneEditing(_ sender: Any) {
    NeedPaymentViewController.details.offer = ""
    NeedPaymentViewController.details.address = ""

    NeedPaymentViewController.details.offer = offerTxt.text!
    NeedPaymentViewController.details.address = addressTxt.text!

    validate()
}
```

Comment: Why your validate function is in another view controller?

Comment: Because I have a pager scrollview which loads  dynamic viewcontrollers.

Comment: Maybe you can use notification to notify the validate method when required

Comment: Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Like MartinM said, I think you would need to make some change to your class logic

Answer (score 0):

You just instantiate your VC, it is not active in the view hierarchy when you call "vc.validate()", so your saveBtn outlet is not yet connected, resulting in the crash.

Anyways ... your structure needs some changes it seems. Have viewcontrollers communicate using delegates, and extract viewcontroller unspecific logic to other classes.

Comment: I can't seem to understand

Comment: Its exactly the same issue you already had in another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375916/swift-access-constraint-from-different-view-controller-found-nil

You cannot just create a new instance of another viewcontroller and access its IBOutlet. It wont get set before viewDidLoad (which is done after presenting it)